# Split array of objects into new array or objects based on age value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Split array of objects into new array or objects based on age value in Javascript

```
var items = [
    {name:"Foo", age:16, color:"w"},
    {name:"Bar", age:18, color:"b"},
    {name:"foo", age:16, color:"w"},
    {name:"bar", age:18, color:"w"},
    {name:"foobar", age:18, color:"b"},
    {name:"barfoo", age:20, color:"w"}
];
```

How can I return a list like:

```
var items = [
    {age:16,name:"Foo"|"foo",gender:"w"|"w"},
    {age:18,name:"Bar"|"bar"|"foobar",gender:"b"|"w"|"b"},
    {age:20,name:"barfoo",gender:"w"}
];
```

I have worked but i got output with 'undefined' in name. Below is my code.

```
var data = [{age: 21,name: "Walter",color: "black"},{age: 25,name: "sentinel",color: "black"
},{age: 21,name: "Micah",color: "purple"},{age: 25,name: "mike",color: "black"},{age: 21,name: "Danny",color: "white"},{age: 25,name: "mike",color: "black"}];
var obj=data;
var arrayobj = obj.length;
var i, row, arr = obj, ss = {};
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    row = arr[i];   
    ss[row.age] = ss[row.age] || {count: 0};
    if (ss[row.age][row.age] === undefined) {                          
        ss[row.age][row.name] = row.name;
        ss[row.age]['name']+=row.name+'|';
        ss[row.age]['color']+=row.color+'|';
        ss[row.age]['count'] += 1;
    }
}
console.table(ss);
```

Comment: Any reason for those `|` ? Did you mean nested arrays? The end result is invalid syntax.

Comment: Like most programming problems, you need to reason about the problem, come up with a suitable algorithm, and implement it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: while not technically invalid syntax, it definitely wasn't what the questioner intended to do.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy you're right, it's not invalid syntax - just amusing syntax with all those bitwise ors :)

Comment: This question is off topic because *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"*.

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming you want to group the items by their age. Here is one way:

([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcV8H/))

```
items.reduce(function(buckets,item){
    if(!buckets[item.age]) buckets[item.age] = [];
    buckets[item.age].push(item);
    return buckets;
},{});
```

Let's explain:

- For each item, if we don't already have a 'bucket' for it, create a new empty one
- Add it to the bucket
- return the new updated bucket list.

The method returns an object with 3 properties: 16,18 and 20, each containing the objects with that age.

Comment: I'm betting OP means for the `|` to be separators within a string. I'm also betting that OP could figure out how to do it given a little effort.

Comment: Nice and concise. It's left for the OP to iterate over buckets calling join('|') over each element's name and color properties.

Comment: @BlueSkies I'm sorry but I couldn't resist the opportunity to `reduce` :) Since this is really a simple one step question - I'm not sure 'what has OP tried' is as relevant here but I totally get that criticism.

Comment: Thanks. I want new array of object. Could you help me.

Comment: @user3026304: Where are you stuck? What do you not know how to do?

Comment: @user3026304 I can help you but I don't understand what you need very well. You might want to go over the syntax of arrays and objects in JavaScript - and how to interact with them first since the syntax in your question is probably not what you mean - http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

Answer (score 1):

This will work. The output is in different format than one provided by **exebook** .

Please check and confirm. [Here's a fiddle....](http://jsfiddle.net/7WK5N/)

** UX Manager

```
var buckets = [];

for (var item in items) {
    var currentAge = items[item].age;

    if(!buckets[currentAge]) {
        buckets[currentAge] = [];
        for (var i in items) {      
            if (currentAge === items[i].age) {
                buckets[currentAge].push(items[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [
     {name:"Foo", age:16, color:"w"},
     {name:"Bar", age:18, color:"b"},
     {name:"foo", age:16, color:"w"},
     {name:"bar", age:18, color:"w"},
     {name:"foobar", age:18, color:"b"},
     {name:"barfoo", age:20, color:"w"}
];

var result = [] // THIS IS THE RESULTING ARRAY THAT YOU WANT

function find(age) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        if (result[i].age == age) return i
    return -1
}

function append(i, obj) {
    result[i].name.push(obj.name)
    result[i].color.push(obj.color)
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var x = find(items[i].age)
    if (x < 0) result.push({ age: items[i].age, name: [items[i].name], color : [items[i].color]})
    else append(x, items[i])
}

console.log(result) // PRINT THE RESULT, alternatively you can use alert(result)
```

The output

```
[ { age: 16, name: [ 'Foo', 'foo' ], color: [ 'w', 'w' ] },
  { age: 18, name: [ 'Bar', 'bar', 'foobar' ], color: [ 'b', 'w', 'b' ] },
  { age: 20, name: [ 'barfoo' ], color: [ 'w' ] } ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this one! This answer is really relevant what i'm expecting.